# Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) based authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth2

IP addresses can change and the FQDN is slightly more constant. So I thought that FQDN based authentication instead of IP based authentication might be a good idea, but I didn't find any information about something like this on the internet so I figured something was causing it not to be used. But what? Wouldn't that be a good alternative to OAuth2 client authentication, for example? What are the problems with FQDN (in the context of authentication), and what realistically causes FQDN-based authentication not to be used?

Comment: Do you mean the client's FQDN? Mine is from my ISP, and it changes every time my IP changes. It's also not sent (by any protocol I know of), so it would be an additional query from the server to get it each time a client connects.

Comment: Are you talking about authenticating the server by its FQDN (which is basically what TLS uses server certificates for), or the client (which won't work, because client FQDNs aren't consistent, unique, or noticeably secure).

Comment: And if the server kept a list of all FQDN clients and checked the received FQDN using reverse DNS (since the FQDN can be assigned to an IP, so when changing IP we set the old FQDN and it still matches that on the server side) would that make sense?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS - *"A FCrDNS verification can create a weak form of authentication that there is a valid relationship between the owner of a domain name and the owner of the network that has been given an IP address."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [Reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) to get the name associated with the IP address is dangerous, since the one owning the IP address could claim arbitrary names in the PTR record. With [Forward confirmed reverse DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) this is not a problem, but attacks like DNS spoofing might still work. Apart from that the management of the DNS setup for the domain is often not in the administration of a specific client system you want to authenticate.

In other words, there is too much what can go wrong and thus FQDN based authentication is only considered a weak form of authentication. Apart from that it does not authenticate a specific application client like OAuth does, but basically an IP address only - i.e. the authentication is at the granularity of the network and not application.